How to automatically calculate characters with spaces for a specific paragraph in word?
As stated in the title, I would like to automatically calculate all characters with spaces within one paragraph. The reason for this is, I am  writing multiple articles and could not keep track of the allowed character limit of one paragraph. The limit is necessary for printing. My text structure looks like this, in a simplified state:
Paragraph [with text] [Characters with spaces: XXXX]
where XXXX is the field function DOCPROPERTY CharactersWithSpaces.
This function is good if I look at the the whole article, but not a single paragraph. I could not find the post on stackoverflow anymore, where this fieldfunction was modified for one paragraph. Is there a way to modify this field function for one paragraph?
For my usual approach, I tried to enter the word {paragraph} in brackets with the paragraph number:
DOCPROPERTY CharactersWithSpaces {Paragraph} 2
or
DOCPROPERTY {Paragraph 2} CharactersWithSpaces
This number was obtained with another DOC property for paragraphs. However, once I update my document, I get the error message that this command name is not known.
